# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, api, utf-8

i have taken this code from https://github.com/davidadamojr/TextRank and i am facing this problem. i tried to solve by placing utf-8 in **"keyphrases = decode('utf-8').extractKeyphrases(text)"**  but failed.

here is the code:

```
"""
From this paper: http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/acl2004/emnlp/pdf/Mihalcea.pdf 

External dependencies: nltk, numpy, networkx

Based on https://gist.github.com/voidfiles/1646117
"""

import nltk
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
import networkx as nx
import sys
import os

#apply syntactic filters based on POS tags
def filter_for_tags(tagged, tags=['NN', 'JJ', 'NNP']):
    return [item for item in tagged if item[1] in tags]

def normalize(tagged):
    return [(item[0].replace('.', ''), item[1]) for item in tagged]

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in itertools.ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element

def lDistance(firstString, secondString):
    "Function to find the Levenshtein distance between two words/sentences - gotten from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python"
    if len(firstString) > len(secondString):
        firstString, secondString = secondString, firstString
    distances = range(len(firstString) + 1)
    for index2, char2 in enumerate(secondString):
        newDistances = [index2 + 1]
        for index1, char1 in enumerate(firstString):
            if char1 == char2:
                newDistances.append(distances[index1])
            else:
                newDistances.append(1 + min((distances[index1], distances[index1+1], newDistances[-1])))
        distances = newDistances
    return distances[-1]

def buildGraph(nodes):
    "nodes - list of hashables that represents the nodes of the graph"
    gr = nx.Graph() #initialize an undirected graph
    gr.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    nodePairs = list(itertools.combinations(nodes, 2))

    #add edges to the graph (weighted by Levenshtein distance)
    for pair in nodePairs:
        firstString = pair[0]
        secondString = pair[1]
        levDistance = lDistance(firstString, secondString)
        gr.add_edge(firstString, secondString, weight=levDistance)

    return gr

def extractKeyphrases(text):
    #tokenize the text using nltk
    wordTokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    #assign POS tags to the words in the text
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(wordTokens)
    textlist = [x[0] for x in tagged]

    tagged = filter_for_tags(tagged)
    tagged = normalize(tagged)

    unique_word_set = unique_everseen([x[0] for x in tagged])
    word_set_list = list(unique_word_set)

   #this will be used to determine adjacent words in order to construct keyphrases with two words

    graph = buildGraph(word_set_list)

    #pageRank - initial value of 1.0, error tolerance of 0,0001, 
    calculated_page_rank = nx.pagerank(graph, weight='weight')

    #most important words in ascending order of importance
    keyphrases = sorted(calculated_page_rank, key=calculated_page_rank.get, reverse=True)

    #the number of keyphrases returned will be relative to the size of the text (a third of the number of vertices)
    aThird = len(word_set_list) / 3
    keyphrases = keyphrases[0:aThird+1]

    #take keyphrases with multiple words into consideration as done in the paper - if two words are adjacent in the text and are selected as keywords, join them
    #together
    modifiedKeyphrases = set([])
    dealtWith = set([]) #keeps track of individual keywords that have been joined to form a keyphrase
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while j < len(textlist):
        firstWord = textlist[i]
        secondWord = textlist[j]
        if firstWord in keyphrases and secondWord in keyphrases:
            keyphrase = firstWord + ' ' + secondWord
            modifiedKeyphrases.add(keyphrase)
            dealtWith.add(firstWord)
            dealtWith.add(secondWord)
        else:
            if firstWord in keyphrases and firstWord not in dealtWith: 
                modifiedKeyphrases.add(firstWord)

            #if this is the last word in the text, and it is a keyword,
            #it definitely has no chance of being a keyphrase at this point    
            if j == len(textlist)-1 and secondWord in keyphrases and secondWord not in dealtWith:
                modifiedKeyphrases.add(secondWord)

        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1

    return modifiedKeyphrases

def extractSentences(text):
    sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    sentenceTokens = sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip())
    graph = buildGraph(sentenceTokens)

    calculated_page_rank = nx.pagerank(graph, weight='weight')

    #most important sentences in ascending order of importance
    sentences = sorted(calculated_page_rank, key=calculated_page_rank.get, reverse=True)

    #return a 100 word summary
    summary = ' '.join(sentences)
    summaryWords = summary.split()
    summaryWords = summaryWords[0:101]
    summary = ' '.join(summaryWords)

    return summary

def writeFiles(summary, keyphrases, fileName):
    "outputs the keyphrases and summaries to appropriate files"
    print "Generating output to " + 'keywords/' + fileName
    keyphraseFile = open('keywords/' + fileName, 'w')
    for keyphrase in keyphrases:
        keyphraseFile.write(keyphrase + '\n')
    keyphraseFile.close()

    print "Generating output to " + 'summaries/' + fileName
    summaryFile = open('summaries/' + fileName, 'w')
    summaryFile.write(summary)
    summaryFile.close()

    print "-"


#retrieve each of the articles
articles = os.listdir("articles")
for article in articles:
    print 'Reading articles/' + article
    articleFile = open('articles/' + article, 'r')
    text = articleFile.read()
    keyphrases = decode('utf-8').extractKeyphrases(text)
    summary = extractSentences(text)
    writeFiles(summary, keyphrases, article)
```

error:

```
Reading articles/1.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\Relevancy\test\TextRank-master\textrank.py", line 166, in <module>
    keyphrases = extractKeyphrases(text).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\Relevancy\test\TextRank-master\textrank.py", line 72, in extractKeyphrases
    wordTokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 93, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 82, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1270, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1318, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1309, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1348, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 354, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1324, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1369, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1504, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 354, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 621, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 586, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any idea? (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
# ...
text = articleFile.read().decode('utf-8')
keyphrases = extractKeyphrases(text)
# ...
```

Basicly you want to decode to an unicode string the contents of the file as soon as you read it. Then the rest of your program is save from conversion problems. Please also make sure the file is actually in utf-8 encoding. If unsure try latin1 as encoding because that will never throw an exception while decoding (but still produces wrong text of course when the file is not in latin1 encoding)